# what is the error on in this titanium alloy controller code?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I am trying to follow the example code in chapter two of "Building Cross- Platform Apps Using Titanium, Alloy, and Appcelerator Cloud Services" by Aaron Saunders.  I get a runtime error which looks like the cars collection is not found even though it is declared in index.js, as seen below:
[image: undefined is not a function]

the relevant code I think is in either in index.js or cars.js  ---

```
    //cars.js
    // Arguments passed into this controller can be accessed via the $.args` object directly or:
var args = $.args;

function doClick(e) {
    alert($.label.text);
}

// controllers/cars.js
function transform(model) {
    // Need to convert the model to a JSON object
    var carObject = model.toJSON();
    return {
        "title" : carObject.model + " by " + carObject.make,
        "id" : model.cid
    };
}
// Show only cars made by Honda
function filter(collection) {
    return collection.where({
        make : 'Honda'
    });
}

// NOTE:  I had to add the id mytable to the xml code for the cars view 
// and then change this line from $.table.add....  to get past 
// another  error on this line 
$.mytable.addEventListener('click', function(_event) {
    // get the correct model
    var model = Alloy.Collections.cars._getByCid(_event.rowData.modelId);
    // create the controller and pass in the model
    var detailController = Alloy.createController('detail', {
        data : model
    });


    // get view returns the root view when no view ID is provided
    detailController.getView().open({
        modal : true
    });
});

 // Free model-view data binding resources when view-controller
// closes
$.mainWindow.addEventListener('close', function() {
    $.destroy();
});
```

and in

```
//index.js
Alloy.Collections.instance("cars");

// I also tried adding --
// Alloy.Collections.cars = Alloy.createCollection('cars'); 
// to alloy.js but the error persists

// also tried adding --
// Alloy.Globals.cars = Alloy.createCollection('cars');
// to alloy.js but still the problem persisted 

var carsController = Alloy.createController("cars");
Alloy.Collections.cars.reset([{
    "make" : "Honda",
    "model" : "Civic"
}, {
    "make" : "Honda",
    "model" : "Accord"
}, {
    "make" : "Ford",
    "model" : "Escape"
},{
    "make" : "Nissan",
    "model" : "Altima"
}]);
//$.mainWindow.open();
carsController.mainWindow.open();
```

the index.xml just has the empty Alloy tags

the cars.xml file:

```
<Alloy>

<Window id="mainWindow" class="container">
    <TableView id="mytable" dataCollection="cars" dataTransform="transform" dataFilter="filter">
        <TableViewRow title="{title}" modelId="{id}"></TableViewRow>
        </TableView>

</Window></Alloy>
```

There is also a detail controller and view but I believe the issue in not in there, if you want to see them let me know and I'll post them.
Please help me figure this error out,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found a github where someone talks about the same code.
https://github.com/ahuimanu/CIDM4385_Chapter03_Demo_Modified/blob/master/app/controllers/cars.js#L35
First I was right to add an id to the tableview in cars.xml  but also it turns out the  function call I copied precisely from the book
Alloy.Collections.cars._getByCid(_event.rowData.modelId);
-- has, I guess, a typo in that it should not have the underscore in the function name --
Alloy.Collections.cars.getByCid(_event.rowData.modelId);

Fixed that and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://backbonejs.org/

**Removed getByCid from Collections. collection.get now supports lookup by both id and cid.**

Comment: Thanks but I think alloy still uses backbone.js version 0.9.2, one before the method was removed,  as I said the getByCid call seems to work now.